# data.table roll="nearest" returns multiple results

Tags: r, data.table

I'm attempting to use `data.table` to match the nearest decimal value in a vector but am running into a situation where more than one result is returned.  The simplified example below returns two values, `0.1818182 0.2727273`, but using a less precise value for `x` (e.g. `0.0275`) returns a single match (`0.1818182`).

```
x = 0.0275016249293408
dt = data.table(rnk = c(0, 0.0909090909090909, 
                        0.181818181818182, 0.272727272727273),
                val = c(0.0233775088495975, 0.0270831481152598, 
                        0.0275016216267234, 0.0275016249293408),
                key="val")
dt[J(x), roll="nearest"][, ifelse(is.na(val), NA_real_, rnk)]
```

I'm assuming the problem is related to the precision of the numeric values I'm using for this comparison.  Is there a limitation to the decimal precision that can be used for a nearest match (i.e. do I need to round the data points)?  Is there a better way to accomplish this nearest match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to Matt's answer there is an easy way to use all the 15 significant digits a double offers in order to properly select the closest matching row. Instead of working on the original values, one can scale the values up to ensure that the 15 significant digits lie above the 10^(-8) level. This could be done as follows:

```
orig_vals <- dt[,val]
scale_fact <- max(10^(trunc(log10(abs(orig_vals)))+8))
scaled_vals <- orig_vals * scale_fact
dt[,scaled_val:=scaled_vals]
setkey(dt,scaled_val)
```

Now, performing the rolling join

```
scaled_x <- x*scale_fact
dt[J(scaled_x), roll="nearest"][, ifelse(is.na(val), NA_real_, rnk)]

# [1] 0.2727273
```

yields - as desired - a single value.
If also in the case of two identical key values only one row should be selected, the `mult="first"` argument can be added to the above `data.table` call.

Comment: +1 Yes that should work in v1.8.10. This discussion is good timing actually as v1.8.11 now does tolerance differently. It now rounds away the 2 most insignificant bytes of the significand (the last 16 bits). So the scaling up trick won't circumvent it any more. The motivation was efficiency (bit twiddling is fast) but also it's more  in line with the reason for doing it (machine accuracy) to round to significant digits. It could be optional though: default 2 bytes rounding, or 1 byte or 0 (turn off rounding). Does that sound ok?

Comment: Sounds great! I would like to have the option to disable the rounding feature. This could be useful if the key column defines a fixed numerical grid and only fast binary searching is required. Then there is no need to give away numerical precision.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, `data.table` automatically applies a tolerance when joining and grouping `numeric` columns. The tolerance in v1.8.10 is `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps) == 1.490116e-08`. This comes directly from `?base::all.equal`.

To illustrate, consider grouping :

```
> dt
          rnk        val
1: 0.00000000 0.02337751
2: 0.09090909 0.02708315
3: 0.18181818 0.02750162
4: 0.27272727 0.02750162

> dt[,.N,by=val]
          val N
1: 0.02337751 1
2: 0.02708315 1
3: 0.02750162 2    # one group, size two
>
```

When you joined using `dt[J(x), roll="nearest"]`, that `x` value matched to within tolerance and you got the group it matched to, as usual when a matching value occurs in a rolling join. `roll="nearest"` only applies to the values that don't match, outside tolerance.

`data.table` considers the values in rows 3 and 4 of `val` to be equal.  The thinking behind this is for convenience, since most of the time key values are really a fixed precision such as prices ($1.23) or recorded measurements to a specified precision (1.234567). We'd like to join and group such `numerics` even after multiplying them for example, without needing to code for machine accuracy ourselves. And we'd like to avoid confusion when `numeric` data displays as though it's equal in a table, but isn't due to very tiny differences in the bit representation.

See `?unique.data.table` for this example :

```
DT = data.table(a=tan(pi*(1/4 + 1:10)), b=rep(1,10))   # example from ?all.equal
length(unique(DT$a))         # 10 strictly unique floating point values
all.equal(DT$a,rep(1,10))    # TRUE, all within tolerance of 1.0
DT[,which.min(a)]            # row 10, the strictly smallest floating point value
identical(unique(DT),DT[1])  # TRUE, stable within tolerance
identical(unique(DT),DT[10]) # FALSE
```

`data.table` is also *stable* within tolerance; i.e, when you group by a `numeric`, the original order of the items within that group are maintained as usual.

```
> dt$val[3] < dt$val[4]   # in your example data, 3 is strictly less than 4
[1] TRUE
> dt[, row:=1:4]  # add a row number to illustrate
> dt[, list(.N, list(row)), by=val]
          val N  V2
1: 0.02337751 1   1
2: 0.02708315 1   2
3: 0.02750162 2 3,4
> dt[3:4, val:=rev(val)]   # swap the two values around
> dt$val[3] > dt$val[4]
[1] TRUE
> dt[, list(.N, list(row)), by=val]
          val N  V2
1: 0.02337751 1   1
2: 0.02708315 1   2
3: 0.02750162 2 3,4    # same result, consistent. stable within tolerance
```